# How to create a travis config file for an asp.net mvc project

Tags: travis-ci

I've create a `.travis.yml` with a respective configuration:

```
language: csharp
solution: project.sln
install:
  - nuget restore project.sln
  - nuget install xunit.runners -Version 1.9.2 -OutputDirectory testrunner
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release project.sln
  - mono ./testrunner/xunit.runners.1.9.2/tools/xunit.console.exe ./project/Model.Core.Tests/bin/Release/Model.Core.Tests.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/xunit.runners.1.9.2/tools/xunit.console.exe ./project/ApplicationService.Tests/bin/Release/ApplicationService.Tests.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/xunit.runners.1.9.2/tools/xunit.console.exe ./project/Presentation.Web.Tests/bin/Release/Presentation.Web.Tests.dll
```

this is the error log.

```
Errors:
/home/travis/build/project/project.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/travis/build/project/Presentation.Web/Presentation.Web.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->
    Controllers/ValidarNovoSiteController.cs(5,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Controller' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(17,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Controller' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    App_Start/FilterConfig.cs(7,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(29,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(35,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(68,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(78,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(88,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(105,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(116,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(123,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(145,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(152,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(166,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(202,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ActionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    Controllers/HomeController.cs(209,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `JsonResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
     9 Warning(s)
     16 Error(s)
```

I wanna build this ASP.NET MVC 5, there is any config detail that I forgot?